# How to solve React custom hook TypeError (0 , _ .default) is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I want to set up a custom hook for data fetching with React Query to easily mock the return values for testing.

This is my `useFetchHook` custom hook.

```
export const useFetchData = (idQuery) => {
  const delay = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 500);
    });
  };

  const handleRickAndMortyFetch = () => {
    return delay()
      .then(() => axios(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${idQuery}`))
      .then((res) => res.data);
  };

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ["rickandmorty", idQuery],
    handleRickAndMortyFetch,
    {
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      enabled: false || idQuery !== 0,
      onError: (error) => console.log(error),
      retry: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      useErrorBoundary: true
    }
  );

  return { data, error, isLoading };
};
```

However, I receive a `TypeError (0 , _useFetchData2.default) is not a function`, which points to this line of code in the `<Home/>`.

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useFetchData(idQuery);
```

These are my attempts to solve the issue

- Try different export methods. `export default function useFetchData(idQuery)` or `export const useFetchData = (idQuery) => {}`
- Assure custom hook is returning values `return { data, error, isLoading }`
- Assure custom hook is invoked and argument is passed. `useFetchData(idQuery)`
- Destructure `useFetchHook` as object as it's returning an object.
  inside `useFetchHook` is `return { data, error, isLoading };`
  inside `<Home/>` is `const { data, error, isLoading } = useFetchData(idQuery);`
- React version is 17.0

Please advise how to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause you "named export" `useFetchData` instead of default export So change To

```
import useFetchData from "../../hooks/useFetchData";
```

in Home.jsx

```
import { useFetchData } from "../../hooks/useFetchData";
```

Or change `export const useFetchData` to `export default useFetchData`